# How do I drop and recreate a Postgresql View with Zero Downtime

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I am looking at using materialized views to keep track of complex statistical data that is refreshed daily.

I need the ability to redefine the structure of the view from time to time as new statistical information is added or removed.

I need to work to a **Zero Downtime** policy.

I will never read directly from these statistical views but instead, go through an Alias View that is pointing at the latest stats view.

I have worked out that by using versioned Materialized Views I can set up a new statistics view, let it rebuild and when ready, point the alias view towards the new version.

What I am not sure of, is whether the recreation of the Alias view could lead to downtime, even if only for **half a second**. I can do the DROP and CREATE in a transaction so maybe I have nothing to worry about, maybe queries will just queue up and start working after the Alias is recreated, but I am not sure and it is mandatory that I have no downtime.

Here is some sample code to show the flow

**Create Materialized View - Version 1**

-- This view takes 20 seconds to create and materialize with data
  create materialized view complex_sql_v01 as
    select a, b, c, d 
    from table1 -- joined onto many other tables;

**Drop and Create Alias View**

```
drop view if exists complex_sql;

create view complex_sql as
  select a, b, c, d from complex_sql_v01;
```

**Rails Active Record to read from Alias View**

```
class ComplexSql < ApplicationRecord
  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```

**Create Materialized View - Version 2**

```
-- This view takes 20 seconds to create and materialize with data
create materialized view complex_sql_v02 as
  select a, c, d, e 
  from table1 -- joined onto many other tables;
```

The next step will not start until well after the version 2 view is in place and loaded with data.

**Drop and Create Alias View**

Note: column b removed, column e added so this can't be down with ALTER VIEW or CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW

```
drop view if exists complex_sql;

create view complex_sql as
  select a, c, d, e from complex_sql_v02;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with downtime? Obviously during the re-creation of the alias view, sessions trying to access the view would have to _wait_. Do you consider waiting as downtime?

Comment: Waiting would be fine, but having a query fail because the view was not there is a problem. I guess I am trying to verify that nothing would fail during the time it takes to drop and recreate the view, but the problem is, I'm not sure if it is testable.

Comment: You have to do the `drop view` and `create view` in a single transaction.

Comment: and so if any requests came in, they would just wait until the transaction was finished.

Comment: If you aren't changing columns or their data types, you can use create or replace view instead of dropping it and re-creating it.  Like dropping it and creating it, this could be done in a transaction and would block while it runs, but it should take much less than a second.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy, I was aware of that, I mentioned it in the last use case that removal of columns will occur.

Comment: @David Cruwys, did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't remember the exact solution, but what I believe I did at the time was create a new mat_view with version number. so my system would have mat_view_01 and mat_view_02, and then I would have are regular view that could point to what ever the latest mat view version was. Today it would be `create view abc as select * from mat_view_01` and tomorrow `create view abc as select * from mat_view_02` and so the code that queries the db always uses the standard view while the mat views can be moved forward as needed. It was a bit fiddly and painful to maintain, but it worked